# Should you sit in the back or the front of Swedish taxis?

Tags: taxis, sweden, cultural-awareness

In most American movies the passengers sit in the back. Is this also the case in Sweden or is it fine to sit in the front passenger seat? Also, the typical London taxi doesn't even have a front passenger seat!

I can easily get motion sick and prefer sitting in the front but the drivers seem bothered as most have their bags in the front passenger seat.

Comment: "In most American movies the passengers sit in the back. Is this also the case in Sweden" --> in Swedish movies?  Movies are fictional.  They do not represent the real world.

Answer (score 6):

I have lived in Nordic countries for more than 10 years. As per my experience, the driver doesn't care whether you seat in front or in the back seat of the car. Most of the car doesn't put their bag in front also so you can easily take front seat.

However, driver never allows you to put luggage in the back seat. It should go in the trunk. Besides that, they speak fluent English too. You can have a good time with them during driving too.

Comment: "Besides that, they speak fluent English too" Native Scandinavians yes, but many drivers immigrated as adults from from countries where English isn't widely known, so those are anything but guaranteed to know it.

Answer (score 4):

Having taken probably hundreds of taxis in Sweden and lived and travelled there many times, I would say that where you sit should not be an issue per se. But, as with anywhere in the world the driver needs to feel comfortable and you might be unlucky to find an awkward one.

If you are unsure then you can also say to them the reason why; most will not have a problem with it. They will soon move their bag, the same as they would if 3 or 4 passengers got into the taxi.

Also, it is worth noting that in Sweden you are not obliged to take the first taxi which is in a taxi rank and you can go down the rank to find one which is more likely to accommodate your request (or is cheaper!).

You also refer to London black cabs not having a front passenger seat. In this case you would need to use a mini-cab company, which you would have to call and hire or use a service like Uber instead.